# unable to print my response in template

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to print my response in my template file

**app.js**

```
.state('intents', {
    url: '/intents',
    templateUrl: '/js/tpl/intents.html',
    controller: 'IntentsController'
})
.state('intentsEdit', {
    url: '/intents/:id',
    templateUrl: '/js/tpl/intentsEdit.html',
    controller: 'IntentsController'
})
```

**intentsEdit.html**

```
<div class="container">{{msg}}
    <p>{{data.name}}</p>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.getIntentsbyId = function(id){
        $scope.id = id;
        $scope.msg = "Text";
        //alert(id);
        $http.get('/api/intents/'+id).success(function(data){
            $scope.dataId = data;
            console.log($scope.dataId);

        });
    }
```

**intents.html**

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="intends in data | filter: searchKeyword">
    <td><a href="#/intents/{{intends.id}}" ng-click="getIntentsbyId(intends.id);" data="{{intends.id}}">{{intends.name}}</a></td>
    <td>{{intends.answer}}</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
```

in my **intentsEdit.html** i am not able to print any response or string

i don't know what is the problem over here

if i print **console.log()** i can able to see but template i am not able to print

Answer (score 0):

first pass response data to $scope.data

```
$scope.getIntentsbyId = function(id){
        $scope.id = id;
        $scope.msg = "Text";
        //alert(id);
        $http.get('/api/intents/'+id).success(function(data){
            $scope.data= data;
            console.log($scope.data);

        });
    }
```

Comment: that's not a problem in console i got data

Comment: Even this $scope.msg = "Text"; also not printing